# Youtube Javascript API play(); not working.. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, swfobject

I'm playing around with YouTubes Javascript API. I've set up a test page on my local enviornment, but the play function is not working. The video loads, and I can press play on the yt video screen, but my link "play" isn't working. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong??

I've been following this: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/javascripts/swfobject.js"></script> 
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="ytapiplayer">
      You will need Flash 8 or better to view this content.
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
      var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
      swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/OQSNhk5ICTI&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer", "ytapiplayer", "425", "365", "8", null, null, params, atts);

      function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
      }

      function play() {
        if (ytplayer) {
          ytplayer.playVideo();
        }
      }
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="play();">Play</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your exact code worked just fine for me on IE, Chrome and Firefox. If you're using one of those add such debugging: `function play() { alert(typeof ytplayer);    if (ytplayer) { alert(ytplayer.playVideo); ytplayer.playVideo(); } }` what alerts do you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't work on a local env. You can download e.g. web developer express which has included a tiny web server, and you can run it in localhost.

Comment: Tested in localhost and your code is working, but file://... without a webserver doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your div id is `ytapiplayer` not <strike>`myytplayer`</strike>
So, change the function onYouTubePlayerReady as

```
 function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    //ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytapiplayer");
  }
```

[`View the fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/L8qMe/1/) to see the code working

Comment: The code in this fiddle isn't working for me - the play button doesn't play the video.

Comment: @nnyby: I will check and let you know. It was working. some change in api maybe.